# I cannot install oracle database 12c on my windows

Tags: oracle

Please help to solve this error. I asked my class mate and prof but they can't solve it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Try to run setup as **administrator** (i.e. user which has access to all directories on your disk).

Comment: Which kind of Windows do you have? Check [Oracle Database Software Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/reqs.htm#NTDBI2698) whether your Windows is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You must launch the installer as user which belongs to "Administrators" group. Using explorer and option "Run as Administrator" does not work.

Before you start installation delete these folders:

- `%TEMP%\deinstall*`
- `%TEMP%\OraInstall*`
- `%TEMP%\CVU*`